# Displaying Lists on Web and Mobile

Tags: lists, tables, responsive-design

I need to show a list of items - some thing like browse all the records on the web and mobile.

Basically its a list of startups and information about the same.

this is a basic version i have come up with 
http://play.mink7.com/h/startupsradar/pending.html

On Mobile i want to display information in a more compact way which is the best way to do that ?

Right now i am using Tables. Should we have a seperate block of HTML to display the list or can we modify the same for the mobile view too ?

I like this list for the mobile.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it seems, list drilldown is the appropriate pattern.

Quoting [Tidwell's book:](http://designinginterfaces.com/patterns/one-window-drilldown/)

**Problem**:

> You have a list of items to show. Each item has interesting content associated with it, such as the text of an email message, a long article, a full-size image, or details about a file’s size or date.
>
> You have very little space to work with—not enough for a Two-Panel Selector or a List Inlay. For instance, the design might be intended for a very small mobile screen, or for a self-contained web page sidebar or widget.

**Suggested Solution**:

> Show a list or menu of items in a single window. When the user selects an item from the list, show the details or contents of that item in the window, replacing the list.

*However*, it depends wether all of the information is needed there to "accept" a startup. If the decision could be made with much fewer elements, consider putting the *Accept* button in the list as well (perhaps, to avoid misclicks with a confirmation solution like what you have in AppStore: single changes button to a confirm button, second click accepts) as well as a big *Accept* button on the detail page.

Don't forget, that Android has built-in back capability, whilst iOS needs an explicit back button, usually located at the top bar next to the title.